# Trying to use Azure Pod Identity fails a number of times, before finally succeeding

Tags: azure-aks

**Intro:** I'm trying to get Azure Pod Identity to work in our cluster to read secrets from a KeyVault, and am mostly succeeding (so far so good). For the time being, we have two keyvaults, two AzureIdentity's, two AzureIdentityBinding's and two Pods using each their keyvault.

While testing, both pods are equal - only difference being their `aadpodidbinding` and an environment variable indicating what keyvault to use. At startup, the pod connects to the KeyVault, reads two values and prints them with `Console.WriteLine`. If the connection fails, the pod will crash and k8s will restart it.

**The problem:** One pod might startup being able to read from the keyvault immediately, while the other will crash and restart for - what seems to be - rather consistently 5 times before being able to get an access token.

When it fails, the following Exception is thrown:

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException: Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/******************. Exception Message: Tried the following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/******************. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. MSI ResponseCode: Forbidden, Response: no AzureAssignedIdentity found for pod:default/kv-test-be

Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/******************. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Environment variable LOCALAPPDATA not set.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/******************. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. No such file or directory

   at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider.GetAuthResultAsyncImpl(String authority, String resource, String scope)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider.<get_KeyVaultTokenCallback>b__8_0(String authority, String resource, String scope)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.PostAuthenticate(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.GetSecretsWithHttpMessagesAsync(String vaultBaseUrl, Nullable`1 maxresults, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.GetSecretsAsync(IKeyVaultClient operations, String vaultBaseUrl, Nullable`1 maxresults, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.LoadAsync()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at KeyvaultTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in /app/src/Program.cs:line 16
```

The behaviour is similar when using FlexVolume (which eventually one group of our pods will use in production), but I find it easier to relate to the error with two equal pods.

While waiting for the pod to succeed, I'm seeing both "binding removed" and "binding applied" messages in mic's log.

**My questions:**

- Is this behaviour "as intendend" and perhaps documented somewhere?
- Is there a setting I can apply to make the "remove - apply" cycle faster?
- Is there anything else that can be done to improve the time between pod creation and the identity binding being applied? Is this issue perhaps related to https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity/issues/145

**Sourcecode**:
Program.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace KeyvaultTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Keyvault read");

            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddAzureKeyVault()
                .Build();

            var test1 = configuration.GetValue<string>("jtest");
            Console.WriteLine(test1);
            var test2 = configuration.GetValue<string>("jtest:jtest");

            Console.WriteLine(test2);
            Console.WriteLine("Finished Keyvault read");
        }
    }
}
```

KeyVaultConfiguration.cs.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault;

namespace KeyvaultTest
{
    public static class KeyVaultConfiguration
    {
        public static IConfigurationBuilder AddAzureKeyVault(this IConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            var builtConfig = builder.Build();
            var keyVaultName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KV_NAME");

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyVaultName))
            {
                throw new Exception("KV_NAME is not defined");
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Using KV_NAME = {keyVaultName}");

            var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                    azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

            builder.AddAzureKeyVault(
                $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/",
                keyVaultClient,
                new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());

            return builder;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help, hints or ideas are much appreciated.

Note: I've posted this same question to the Issue board on of the project's github page https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity/issues/181

Answer (score 0):

We were facing the same issue. We overcame this issue by upgrading AAD Pod Identity. Our version was 1.5 and upgrading this one to 1.7 resolved our issue.

Before that, we had also upgraded the packages (Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication & Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets) that our applications were using to the latest versions but it wasn't enough.